# Global messages not displaying in <rich:messages>

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, message

I have a JSF 2.1 + RichFaces 4.0 webapp on JBoss EAP 6.0. I am not able to display custom error messages from bean to user using `FacesMessage`. I am adding a message using `addMessage()`. However, the message does not show up in `<rich:messages>` and in my console I am getting:

> INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8888-3) WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
>   sourceId=null[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(mobile no should be greater than 10 degits), detail=()].

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <ui:composition>
        <h:head/>
        <link href="../../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />      
        <h:form id="personform12" >
            <h:panelGrid id="test2343" width="80%">
                <rich:messages id="messages" globalOnly="true" errorClass="globalError" showSummary="true" showDetail="false"></rich:messages>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid border="0" columns="3" width="90%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" >
                <h:panelGroup styleClass="alignmentRight">
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle['id']}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:inputText id="id" value="#{personBean.pdto.id}" required="true">
                </h:inputText>
                <rich:message styleClass="error" for="id" />

                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle['name']}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:inputText id="name" value="#{personBean.pdto.name}" required="true"/>
                <rich:message styleClass="error" for="name" />

                <h:panelGroup styleClass="alignmentRight">
                    <h:outputText value="city" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:inputText id="city" value="#{personBean.pdto.city}" required="true"/>
                <rich:message styleClass="error" for="city" />

                <h:panelGroup styleClass="alignmentRight">
                    <h:outputText value="state" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:inputText id="state" value="#{personBean.pdto.state}" required="true"/>
                <rich:message styleClass="error" for="state" />

                <h:panelGroup styleClass="alignmentRight">
                    <h:outputText value="mobile" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:inputText id="mobile" value="#{personBean.pdto.mobile}" required="true">
                </h:inputText>
                <rich:message styleClass="error" for="mobile" />


                <h:panelGroup styleClass="alignmentRight">
                    <h:outputText value="DOB" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <rich:calendar style="height:25px" inputStyle="width:203px" required="true"
                                                    showWeeksBar="false"
                                                     boundaryDatesMode="scroll"
                                                    id="dob" value="#{personBean.pdto.dob}"
                                                    datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy" cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px" />
                <rich:message styleClass="error" for="dob" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <br/><br/>
            <h:commandButton id="commandSubmit" value="Submit" action="#{personBean.save}"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Model:

```
public class PersonJSFBean {

    private static final Logger  log = Logger.getLogger(PersonJSFBean.class);
    private PersonDTO pdto;
    private PersonManager personManager;

    public String save(){
        String str = null;
        try {

            if(pdto.getMobile().length()<10) {
                System.out.println("inside the mobile no>>>>>>>>>>>"+pdto.getMobile());
                FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "mobile no should be greater than 10 degits ", null);
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMsg);

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured>>>>>>>>>>>");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return str;

    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no template attribute in ui:composition I assume the page is top level one. Then **h:body** is missing, here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <h:head/>
    <h:body>
        <h:form .....
    </h:body>
</html>
```